# loading large JSON file data into angular cli table

Tags: json, angular, http, json-server

I have a JSON file with more than 200000 records in it.

I'm using Angular CLI for accessing JSON data with the help of json-server API for accessing it locally.

Im using Angular http request to access JSON, it is getting displayed into browser but not into angular table component.

I checked if ill be able to access it with less number of records then it got displayed, with upto 1000 records i have checked but max i don't know how much it access.

so i just want any solution for accessing large JSON data into angular view efficiently.

please suggest any solution or alternative for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be opinionated answer but you've many options.

1. Try lazy loading table data.
2. Implement Infinite Scroll by loading 50 rows initially & when user reach end of table, load next 50 and so on. Use following plugin for that to minimize your code.

   **[ngInfiniteScroll](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/index.html)**
3. Add pagination to table by using custom filter on ngFor to filter out elements with their index no. You can use following awesome plugin lib

   **[ngx-pagination](http://michaelbromley.github.io/ngx-pagination/#/)**
4. Make use of grids. This is best performance, reliable solution. There are many grids like ag-grid, slickgrid, Angular data table, etc use according to requirement. ag-grid is Angular supported and slickgrid is pure js grid but you can surely configure inside angular project. Also you can try data tables from PrimeNg.
   With using grids, searching, filtering, exporting table data becomes very efficient.

   **[ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/)**

   **[Angular DataTables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome)**

   **[SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid)**

   **[PrimeNG Table](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table)**